# Flutter- Is there a way to set all AppBars elevation

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to set all pages `AppBar`'s `elevation` to 0. Do I have to set individually? Or is there any way to set it to all pages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an easy way of doing it.

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(elevation: 0)
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 8):

Create your own `AppBar` Widget and use it in all your screens

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  class MyAppBar extends AppBar {
    MyAppBar(
        {Key key,
       Widget title,
        Color backgroundColor,
        List<Widget> actions,
        PreferredSizeWidget bottom})
        : super(
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
            title: title,
            actions: actions,
            bottom: bottom,
            elevation:
                0.0,
          );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the app_bar.dart file, the default elevation given to the app bar is 4.0,
You can change that to 0.0. I think that'll do the trick.

Comment: I get what you mean, but this is a terrible idea, since those changes to the source code won't get pushed to git, so the app will look different on every other machine.

Never change the source code of the framework locally -- use built-in mechanics or build your own version instead.